# How to web scrape title after specific class?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape some information on the following website: https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1
I would like to scrape all the movies title, years and the length of the movie.

Here is my code to try to scrape the information

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1&language=yue')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
all_title = soup.find_all(class_="ng-star-inserted")
print(all_title)
```

However, I can't scrape anything into the list.

My expected output:

```
Title                             Year       Length
10 Things I Hate About You        1999       97
17 Again                          2009       102
1778 Stories of Me and My Wife    2011       140
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use puppeteer to scrap that website. It's javascript based so you'll need to wait until the website is fully loaded.

https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

async def get_data():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1", waitUntil="networkidle0")

    html = await page.content()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # Now handle the data

    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_data())
```

Comment: So how do I scrape after I loaded the function?

Comment: So in the var html you have the raw webpage html with the loaded content. Use it to point to the class you want.

Comment: I've tried to use the class 'ng-star-inserted' to find the title, but it points out to many messy things. How to point out the specific title, years and length of each movie?

Comment: I suggest you to to loop the div with the class "gridItem ng-star-inserted" And then get the items in it.https://i.imgur.com/Br2Hrlk.png